# Customized SharePoint metadata alerts

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I was asked about a requirement for a SharePoint site to create email alerts based on metadata. So anytime someone would upload a document and tag it with certain metadata or write a blog with the same metadata, subscribed user would get an alert.

To recap:
- users will pick their metadata from a list
- user get an alert anytime new item is created with their selected metadata

Comment: **users will pick their metadata from a list** means the metadata that user updated should be sent via an email